# Where is the battery animation called when charger connected to phone (OFF)?

Tags: rooting, battery, charging, boot, shell

I have Moto E (Rooted) which turn on when connected with USB via Laptop but not when connected to Wall charger instead it shows Battery animation. I got to know that battery animation is at `framework-res.apk.`

Now I want to know from where it is called so that i can change it as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got the solution, you can achieve this by deleting `system/bin/charge_only_mode` file. Please do that at your own risk and before deleting have backup of that file. I got the desired result that was boot when its connected to wall charger and now its working fine. All the best!